# Edit mp3 tags remotely from Windows

Tags: windows, software-rec, remote, mp3

I have a Windows desktop at home.  My mp3's are on a dedicated Debian server.  How do I edit the mp3 tags on the Linux server from my windows PC with a GUI software?  Is there a GUI software that can connect to Linux and only edit the mp3 tags.

I do not want to download the entire mp3 files and then re-upload it.  There thousands of mp3s on the server.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways: either run a Linux MP3 tag editor and arrange for it to display on your Windows machine, or run a Windows MP3 tag editor and arrange for your Windows machine to see the Linux machine's files.

### Run a Linux GUI program from Windows

On Linux, SSH lets you run commands remotely. This includes the ability to run GUI applications on the remote machine and have them display locally, thanks to [X11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) forwarding. On Windows, you'll need to install [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) (or some other SSH client) and [Xming](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/) (or some other X11 server). XMing ships with a portable version of PuTTY. There are also several collections of portable Windows freeware that include both ([the Portable Freeware Collection](http://www.portablefreeware.com/?id=419), [XMing+PuTTY on a stick](http://www.scrc.umanitoba.ca/doc/tutorial/T19_3a_xmingputty.htm), …). In the PuTTY configuration, under “Connection → SSH → X11”, make sure to enable X11 forwarding and set the “X display location” to `localhost:0` (see e.g. [this tutorial](http://www.geo.mtu.edu/geoschem/docs/putty_install.html)).

### See a remote Linux's files on Windows

For a Linux machine on the local network, installing a [Samba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_%28software%29) server on Linux is the way to go. In Debian, install the [`samba`](http://packages.debian.org/samba) package. On Windows, mount a network drive. However this is difficult to secure if the connection goes via the Internet as in your case.

The preferred way to communicate with a distant Linux machine is SSH, but Windows doesn't support SSH natively, and Windows isn't good at supporting custom types of filesystems. Nonetheless, you can try [Win-sshfs](http://code.google.com/p/win-sshfs/) or perhaps [SFTP Net Drive](https://www.eldos.com/sftp-net-drive/), either of which should let you access your remote files from Windows.